# Referencing sheets by cells with their names

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have four sheets each with its own name which corresponds to the left cells. I want to reference those sheets by only stating the left cells. For example, instead of having `='SIN PLANIFICACIÓN'!E118` in `C3`, I have something of the likes of `=$B3!E118`. So I can drag this formula down and automatically reference other sheets.

How can I do this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

`INDIRECT` is the function you need.

`=INDIRECT("'" & $B3 & "'!E118")`

This will work if you are always referencing the same cell on each sheet.

However, if you want that cell reference to also change as you drag down the formula, this won't work as the `E118` is text and Excel won't auto-increment it.  In that case you would need this:

`=INDIRECT("'" & $B3 & "'!E" & ROW() + 115)`

`ROW()` just returns the number of the row that your formula is on, so that the formula in cell `C4` will be on row 4 and you will get a reference to `E119`.

*Note: The `'` character is necessary when you have spaces in the sheet names, but will work if you have no spaces also.*